# Add a priority column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe(**input_dataframe**) which looks like below:

```
**id**  **col1**  **col2**  **col3**  **col4** **col_check**
   101      1        0          1         1        -1
   102      0        1          1         0        -1
   103      1        1          0         1        -1
   104      0        0          1         1        -1
```

I want to have a PySpark function(**update_col_check**), which update column(**col_check**) of this dataframe. I will pass one column name as an argument to this function. Function should check if value of that column is **1**, then update value of **col_check** as this column name., let us say i am passing **col2** as an argument to this function:

```
output_dataframe = update_col_check(input_dataframe, col2)
```

So, my **output_dataframe** should look like below:

```
**id**  **col1**  **col2**  **col3**  **col4** **col_check**
   101      1        0          1         1        -1
   102      0        1          1         0        col2
   103      1        1          0         1        col2
   104      0        0          1         1        -1
```

Can i achieve this using PySpark? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly straight forward with functions `when`, `otherwise`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit

def update_col_check(df, col_name):
    return df.withColumn('col_check', when(df[col_name] == 1, lit(col_name)).otherwise(df['col_check']))

update_col_check(df, 'col1').show()
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|col_check|
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+
|101|   1|   0|   1|   1|     col1|
|102|   0|   1|   1|   0|       -1|
|103|   1|   1|   0|   1|     col1|
|104|   0|   0|   1|   1|       -1|
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+

update_col_check(df, 'col2').show()
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|col_check|
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+
|101|   1|   0|   1|   1|       -1|
|102|   0|   1|   1|   0|     col2|
|103|   1|   1|   0|   1|     col2|
|104|   0|   0|   1|   1|       -1|
+---+----+----+----+----+---------+
```